# Cant get this private route to work on react-router

Tags: reactjs, typescript, react-router-dom, vite

I just want to send the non verified users to `"/verify"`

PrivateRoute

```
import React from 'react';
import { Navigate, Outlet } from 'react-router-dom';
import { useSelector } from 'react-redux';

const PrivateRoute = () => {
    const isLoggedIn = useSelector((state: any) => state.auth.authentication);
    const profile: any = isLoggedIn?.profile;
    const isVerified: boolean = profile?.verified;
    const hasSubscription: any = profile?.subscription;
    console.log('verified: ', isVerified);
    if (isLoggedIn) {
        if (!isVerified) {
            console.log('need to go to verify');
                return <Navigate to='/verify' replace />;
        } else {
        return <Outlet />;
        }
    } else {
        return <Navigate to='/login' />;
    }

    return <Navigate to='/login' />;

    // return isLoggedIn ? <Outlet /> : <Navigate to='/login' />;
};

export default PrivateRoute;
```

app.tsx

```
<BrowserRouter>
  <Routes>
    <Route path='/login' element={<PublicRoute />}>
      <Route path='/login' element={<Login />} />
    </Route>
    <Route path='/register' element={<PublicRoute />}>
      <Route path='/register' element={<Register />} />
    </Route>
    <Route path='/reset-password' element={<PublicRoute />}>
      <Route path='/reset-password' element={<ResetPassword />} />
    </Route>
    <Route path='/forgot-password' element={<PublicRoute />}>
      <Route path='/forgot-password' element={<ForgetPassword />} />
    </Route>
    {/* <Route path='/subscription' element={<PublicRoute />}>
      <Route path='/subscription' element={<Subscription />} />
    </Route> */}

    <Route path='/' element={<PrivateRoute />}>
      <Route path='/verify' element={<Verify />} />
      <Route path='/' element={<Main />}>
        <Route path='/profile' element={<Profile />} />
        <Route path='/socialcalendar' element={<SocialCalendar />} />
        <Route path='/subscription' element={<Subscription />} />
        <Route index element={<Navigate to='/socialcalendar' />} />
        {/* <Route path='/' element={<Daily />} /> */}
        {/* <Route path='/dashboard' element={<Dashboard />} /> */}
      </Route>
    </Route>
    <Route path='*' element={<Navigate to='/login' />} />
  </Routes>
</BrowserRouter>
```

It's just that when the user is not verified it goes to `"/verify"` as seen in the url, but it just renders a blank page and no code from the verify page is being run.

I just want to get the verify page when user is not verified.

**EDIT:**

```
const login = async (email: string, password: string) => {
        try {
            console.log('login requesrt sent from login');

            setAuthLoading(true);

            const response: any = await authLogin(email, password);
            dispatch(setAuthentication(response as any));
            toast.success('Login is succeeded!');
            setAuthLoading(false);
            console.log(response.profile.verified);
            await new Promise((resolve) => setTimeout(resolve, 100));
            // if (!response.profile.verified) {
            //  navigate('/verify');
            // } else {
            //  navigate('/socialcalendar')
            //  // if (
            //  //  !response.profile?.subscription ||
            //  //  response.profile.subscription.status === 'paused' ||
            //  //  (response.profile.subscription.status === 'future' &&
            //  //      response.profile.subscription.deleted === true) ||
            //  //  response.profile.subscription.status === 'cancelled'
            //  // )
            //  //  navigate('/subscription');
            //  // else navigate('/socialcalendar');
            // }
            navigate('/socialcalendar');
        } catch (error: any) {
            setAuthLoading(false);
            toast.error(error.message || 'Failed');
        }
    };
```

the above is the code i am using for login.

as you can see I have to use that setTimeout , or else it loads the "/socialcalendar" instead of "/verify" no matter the user is verified or not

Comment: FWIW adding a tag to a post alone doesn't effect any code syntax highlighting. You should use appropriate code-block fencing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Protected routes can't redirect to other protected routes under the same layout route. This is likely creating a render loop of sorts where a resolved route isn't reachable because the UI keeps redirecting.

Move the `"/verify"` route out of the layout route that protects it.

I suggest refactoring and splitting the `PrivateRoute` component into two separate components. One that only checks if a user is authenticated, and the other that requires them to also be verified. The routes that are nested inside both `PrivateRoute` and `VerifiedRoute` will need both, while routes nested only inside `PrivateRoute` need authentication. If users are not authenticated they are redirected to the login page, if they are missing the verification where it's needed they are redirected to the verify page.

```
import React from 'react';
import { Navigate, Outlet } from 'react-router-dom';
import { useSelector } from 'react-redux';

const PrivateRoute = () => {
  const isLoggedIn = useSelector((state: any) => state.auth.authentication);

  return isLoggedIn
    ? <Outlet />
    : <Navigate to="/login" replace />;
};

export default PrivateRoute;
```

```
import React from 'react';
import { Navigate, Outlet } from 'react-router-dom';
import { useSelector } from 'react-redux';

const VerifiedRoute = () => {
  const isVerified = useSelector((state: any) => {
    return !!state.auth.authentication?.profile?.verified;
  });

  return isVerified
    ? <Outlet />
    : <Navigate to='/verify' replace />;
};

export default VerifiedRoute;
```

```
<BrowserRouter>
  <Routes>
    <Route element={<PublicRoute />}>
      <Route path='/login' element={<Login />} />
      <Route path='/register' element={<Register />} />
      <Route path='/reset-password' element={<ResetPassword />} />
      <Route path='/forgot-password' element={<ForgetPassword />} />
      <Route path='/subscription' element={<Subscription />} />
    </Route>

    <Route element={<PrivateRoute />}>
      <Route path='/verify' element={<Verify />} /> // <-- outside VerifiedRoute

      <Route element={<VerifiedRoute />}>
        <Route element={<Main />}>
          <Route path='/profile' element={<Profile />} />
          <Route path='/socialcalendar' element={<SocialCalendar />} />
          <Route path='/subscription' element={<Subscription />} />
          <Route index element={<Navigate to='/socialcalendar' />} />
          {/* <Route path='/' element={<Daily />} /> */}
          {/* <Route path='/dashboard' element={<Dashboard />} /> */}
        </Route>
      </Route>
    </Route>
    <Route path='*' element={<Navigate to='/login' />} />
  </Routes>
</BrowserRouter>
```

Comment: Okay, it technically it is a protected route
as in, only logged-in users can go to the verify page.
So, there is something else I can do ?

Comment: Or should I just make sure while logging in and registering, go to “/verify”

Comment: @AyushJaipuriyar You can implement another type of protected route component, e.g. one where users only need to be authenticated, and another where they need to be authenticated ***and*** verified. Does this make sense? Need an example? I'm guessing all but the `"/verify"` route need the latter while verify need only the auth?

Comment: I think they should be both authenticated and verified to access any of the private routes, is what I was thinking.
Yeah so can you help me with what you were saying ?
An example would help a lot

Comment: @AyushJaipuriyar I can certainly provide an example. I'd like to first clarify what your verify use case is though. Is a verify step part of a user registration flow? In other words, before a user can really be considered an authenticated user must they register an account, and then verify it, before being able to fully log in? If so then it might make sense to couple the `"/verify"` route with the `"/register"` route. Or can a user be registered and authenticated, and verification is really just an extra thing? Based on your comment it sounds like the former.

Comment: Its like after user registers , they should go to the "/verify" as the verified field in the db is set to false, this verify page takes the otp sent to their email and checks and changes it to true.
So the flow should be like
register -> isverified ? (other private routes) : "/verify"  (register endpoint sends the user data so the user is authenticated)
login ->isauthenticated ? (isverified ? (other private routes) : "/verify") : "/login"

Comment: @AyushJaipuriyar I think I understand. So just to reiterate, you want all the "private routes" except `"/verify"` to only allow users that are both authenticated ***and*** verified, and for specifically the `"/verify"` to only allow users that are authenticated ***but not*** verified?

Comment: Yes, you got that correct.

Comment: @AyushJaipuriyar Ok, answer is updated. I believe this should be close to the behavior you describe wanting. Please check it when you have time.

Comment: Thanks a lot, yes this works just as expected.
I thought of this but wasn't working, must have written something wrong.